# How fromIntegral or read works

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

The `fromIntegral` returns a `Num` data type. But it seems that `Num` is able to coerce to `Double` or `Integer` with no issue. Similarly, the `read` function is able to return whatever that is required to fit its type signature. How does this works? And if I do need to make a similar function, how do I do it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "_Num is able to coerce to Double or Integer with no issue_"?

Comment: `Num` is not a type.  I think your questions can be answered by learning about type classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type checker is able to infer not only the types of function arguments but also the return type. Actually there is no special case there. If you store the result of `fromIntegral` or `read` in `Integer`, the version for this type will get called. You can create your own function in the same way.

For example:

```
class Foo a where
  foo :: a

instance Foo Integer where
  foo = 7

instance Foo String where
  foo = "Hello"

x :: Integer
x = 3

main = do
  putStrLn foo
  print (foo + x)
```

Because `putStrLn` has type `String -> IO ()` the type checker finds that the type of `foo` in `putStrLn foo` must be `String` for the program to compile. The type of `foo` is `Foo a => a`. So it deduces that `a == String` and searches for `Foo String` instance. Such instance exists and it causes the`foo :: Foo String => String` value to be selected there.

Similar reasoning happens in `print (foo + x)`. `x` is known to be `Integer`, and because the type of `(+)` is `Num a => a -> a -> a` the type checker deduces that the left argument of the addition operator must also be `Integer` so it searches for `Foo Integer` instance and substitutes the `Integer` variant.

There is no direction from function arguments to (possible) return type like in C++. The type checker may even deduce function arguments based on knowledge of what the function is expected to return. Another example:

```
twice :: a -> [a]
twice a = [a,a]

y :: [Integer]
y = twice foo
```

The function argument here is of type `Foo a => a` which is not enough to decide which `foo` to use. But because the result is already known to be `[Integer]` the type checker finds that it has to provide value of type `Integer` to `twice` and does so by using the appropriate instance of `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

`read` is a member of a [typeclass](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html) which means that its implementation can depend on a type parameter.

Also, numeric literals like `1`, `42`, etc. are syntatic sugar for function calls `fromInteger 1`, `fromInteger 42`, etc., and `fromInteger` itself is a member of the Num typeclass.

Thus, the literal `42` (or `fromInteger 42`) can return an `Int` or `Double` or any other Num instance depending on the context in which it is called.

Answer (score 2):

I'm being a little particular about terminology here, because I think the words you're using betray some misunderstandings about how Haskell works.

> The fromIntegral returns a Num data type.

More precisely, `fromIntegral` takes as input any type that has an instance of `class Integral`, and can return any type that is an instance of `class Num`.  The prelude defines it like this:

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
fromIntegral = fromInteger . toInteger
```

Types with an `Integral` instance implement the`toInteger` function, and all types with a `Num` instance implement `fromInteger`.  `fromIntegral` uses the `toInteger` associated with the `Integral a` instance to turn a value of type `a` into an Integer.  Then it uses the `fromInteger` from the `Num b` instance to convert that Integer into a value of type `b`.

> But it seems that Num is able to coerce to Double or Integer with no issue.

Every time a haskell function is used, it is "expanded".  Its definition is substituted for the function call, and the parameters used are substituted into the definition.  Each time it is expanded in a different context, it can have different types in its type variables.  So each time a function is expanded, it takes certain concrete types and returns a certain concrete type.  It doesn't return a typeless thing that gets coerced at some later time.

> Similarly, the read function is able to return whatever that is required to fit its type signature.

```
read :: Read a => String -> a
```

`read` takes a `String` as input, and can be used in any context that returns values of a type for which an instance of `class Read` exists.  When it is expanded during execution of a program, this type is known.  It uses the particular definitions in the `Read a` instance to parse the string into the correct type.